# cocoapodsでのAlamofire-SwiftyJSONのインストールおよびビルドについて

Tags: ios, swift

cocoapodsでalamofire、swiftyjson、alamofire-swiftyjsonの3つのライブラリをインストールしたのですが、podのalamofire-swiftyjson.swiftでビルドエラーとなってしまいます。

Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

/Test4/Pods/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON/Source/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON.swift:16:11: error: use of undeclared type 'Request'
extension Request {

環境
OS X 10.10.3
xcode6.3
cocoapods 0.36.3

Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'xcode6.3'
pod 'Alamofire-SwiftyJSON', :git => "https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON.git"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

クロージャのカッコを省略せずに書いてみてください。

リンク先の例で言うと、`.responseSwiftyJSON {`の部分を`.responseSwiftyJSON({`とカッコを開いて、最後の`}`のところで`})`とカッコを閉じてください。

そうすると下のようになります。これでエラーが消えませんか？

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: data).responseSwiftyJSON({ (_, _, json, error) in
    if (error != nil) {
        println("Error with registration: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        println("Success!")
    }
})
```

Comment: responseSwiftyJSON({ })に変更することでエラーが消えました。
具体的にコードを記載していただいたので、分かりやすかったです。

Answer (score 1):

Alamofireモジュール等がビルドできていないことが原因でした。

XCODEの左上の■ボタンの右隣のビルドターゲットにAlamofire等が表示されていなかったので、
Manage Schemes で Pods-[Target名]-Alamofire等のShowにチェックを入れました。

するとビルドターゲットに表示されたので、Alamofire、SwiftyJSON、Alamofire-SwiftyJSONの
順番でビルドしてから、自分のプロジェクトを最後にビルドすると、該当のエラーは消えました。

しかし、今度は下記のエラーが出ています。

Ambiguous use of 'responseSwiftyJSON'
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON/issues/21